# Acceptor refusing to open socket only for -O0 build

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

Hi dear stackoverflow community,

(edit: single file version at the end)

I have a problem only in certain compilation settings (which indicates some kind of UB, but I decided to tag this question as boost-asio since it might involve knowledge about asio specifics). Note that I use the current git version of the standalone asio library.

First let me drop some snippets - the complete code is here:
https://github.com/paulhilbert/magellan
(note that the CMakeLists.txt is very hacky and might need fixing in case you would want to compile it).

I have a test echo server (tcp, async) in examples/echo_server.cpp:

```
[snip...]
int main (int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    try {
        if (argc != 2) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: echo_server <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        asio::io_context io_context;
        magellan::server server;
        server.accept<echo_session>(io_context, 9003);
        io_context.run();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Obviously the interesting parts are the `server` and `echo_session` classes; however the latter seems to work correctly, so I am gonna drop the `server` class here. The include/server.hpp:

```
#ifndef MAGELLAN_SERVER_HPP_
#define MAGELLAN_SERVER_HPP_

#include "session.hpp"

namespace magellan {

class server {
    public:
        [snip typedefs...]

    public:
        server();

        virtual ~server();

        template <typename Session>
        void accept(asio::io_context& io_context, short port);

        [snip comments...]
};

} // magellan

#include "server.ipp"

#endif /* MAGELLAN_SERVER_HPP_ */
```

... and the include/server.ipp:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace magellan {

template <typename Session>
inline void
server::accept(asio::io_context& io_context, short port) {
    using asio::ip::tcp;
    asio::spawn(io_context, [&](asio::yield_context yield) {
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));

        for (;;) {
            asio::error_code ec;
            tcp::socket socket(io_context);
            acceptor.async_accept(socket, yield[ec]);
            if (!ec) {
                auto session = std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(socket));
                session->start();
            }
        }
    });
}

[snip comments...]

} // magellan
```

Now the interesting thing is that the `async_accept` opens a tcp socket iff I compile with -O1, -O2 and -O3, but not with -O0. I checked this via:

```
> ss -a | grep 9003
296:tcp    LISTEN     0      128     *:9003                  *:*
```

When compiled with -O0 the socket is never opened. I also checked that the service is still running via an io_context::work instance.

My best guess (admittedly lacking confidence) is that boost coroutine does something different with -O0. It may also be worth mentioning that if I use the commented out code in server.ipp it also won't open sockets (no matter what compilation settings):

```
template <typename Session>
inline void
server::accept(asio::io_context& io_context, short port) {
    using asio::ip::tcp;
    accept<Session>(io_context, port, [](tcp::socket s) {
        return std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(s));
    });
}

template <typename Session, typename Func>
void
server::accept(asio::io_context& io_context, short port, Func&& factory) {
    using asio::ip::tcp;
    asio::spawn(io_context, [&](asio::yield_context yield) {
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));

        for (;;) {
            asio::error_code ec;
            tcp::socket socket(io_context);
            acceptor.async_accept(socket, yield[ec]);
            if (!ec) {
                auto session = factory(std::move(socket));
                session->start();
            } else {
                std::cout << "failed accept" << "\n";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This was my initial problem and I attributed it to a copied instead of moved socket until I arrived at the -O0 flag problem.

I am pretty lost at this point as I have no idea how to debug these async processes in general but am still confident the actual answer to my question will be in some way embarassing ;)

Hope you have a hint for me.

Best,
Richard

Edit:

Here is a condensed single file version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio/spawn.hpp>
using asio::ip::tcp;

namespace magellan {

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
public:
    session(asio::ip::tcp::socket socket) : socket_(std::move(socket)), strand_(socket_.get_io_context()) {
    }

    template <typename Func>
    void
    async_do(Func&& f) {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        asio::spawn(strand_, [this, self, f](asio::yield_context yield) {
            try {
                f(std::ref(socket_), std::ref(yield));
            } catch (std::exception& e) {
                socket_.close();
            }
        });
    }

    void start() {
        async_do([this] (tcp::socket& s, asio::yield_context& yc) {
            perform(s, yc);
        });
    }

protected:
    virtual void perform(asio::ip::tcp::socket& s, asio::yield_context&) {
        s.close();
    }

protected:
    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
    asio::io_context::strand strand_;
};

class server {
    public:
        typedef std::shared_ptr<server>       ptr;
        typedef std::weak_ptr<server>         wptr;
        typedef std::shared_ptr<const server> const_ptr;
        typedef std::weak_ptr<const server>   const_wptr;

    public:
        server() {}

        virtual ~server() {}

        template <typename Session>
        void
        accept(asio::io_context& io_context, short port) {
            using asio::ip::tcp;
            asio::spawn(io_context, [&](asio::yield_context yield) {
                tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));

                for (;;) {
                    asio::error_code ec;
                    tcp::socket socket(io_context);
                    acceptor.async_accept(socket, yield[ec]);
                    if (!ec) {
                        auto session = std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(socket));
                        session->start();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
};

} // magellan

class echo_session : public magellan::session {
    public:
        typedef std::shared_ptr<echo_session>       ptr;
        typedef std::weak_ptr<echo_session>         wptr;
        typedef std::shared_ptr<const echo_session> const_ptr;
        typedef std::weak_ptr<const echo_session>   const_wptr;

    public:
        echo_session(tcp::socket socket)
            : magellan::session(std::move(socket)) {}

        virtual ~echo_session() {}

    protected:
        void perform(asio::ip::tcp::socket& s, asio::yield_context& yc) {
            char data[128];
            for (;;) {
                std::size_t n = s.async_read_some(asio::buffer(data), yc);
                asio::async_write(s, asio::buffer(data, n), yc);
            }
        }
};


int main (int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    try {
        if (argc != 2) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: echo_server <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        asio::io_context io_context;
        magellan::server server;
        server.accept<echo_session>(io_context, 9003);
        io_context.run();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend minimizing the code as much as possible to a small, self-contained, compilable example. Without seeing everything, it's hard to know if you're triggering undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: I try to write a condensed version

Comment: Added a single file version.... Compile with:  `g++ -std=c++14 -o echo_server echo_server.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_coroutine -lpthread` and the corresponding optimization flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a race condition that can result in dangling references being accessed, invoking undefined behavior. The lambda capture-list is capturing the automatic variables, `port` and `io_service`, by reference. However, the lifetime of `port` may end before it is used to construct the `acceptor`.  In this case, the undefined behavior will most likely result in the program binding to a random port, but it could fail out in other ways.

```cpp
void server::accept(asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
{
  using asio::ip::tcp;
  asio::spawn(io_context, [&](asio::yield_context yield)
  {
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context,
      tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
                            // ~~~~ lifetime may have ended
    ...
  }
}
```

To resolve this, capture `port` by value in the lambda-capture.  Change:

```cpp
[&](boost::asio::yield_context yield) { ... }
```

to:

```cpp
[port, &io_service](boost::asio::yield_context yield) { ... }
```

---

The following example is based on the original code and can (sometimes) [demonstrate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e18cb9cb74d9f91f) the race condition:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

class server
{
public:
  void accept(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
  {
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    std::cout << "port in accept: " << port << std::endl;
    boost::asio::spawn(io_service, [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
      std::cout << "port in coroutine: " << port << std::endl;
      tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
      assert(acceptor.is_open());
      std::cout << "open on port " << acceptor.local_endpoint() << std::endl;
      tcp::socket socket(io_service);
      acceptor.async_accept(socket, yield);
    });
  }
};

int main ()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    server server; 
    server.accept(io_service, 12345);
    std::cout << "running io_service" << std::endl;
    io_service.run();
    assert(false);
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output from one run:

```
port in accept: 12345
running io_service
port in coroutine: 0
open on port 0.0.0.0:58424
```

As can be seen in the output, `port` had the expected value within `server::accept()`, but within the coroutine, the dangling-reference resulted in `port` having a value of `0`, causing the acceptor to bind to a random port.

Comment: You my sir made my day just before it ended. I actually verified that `port` is correct, but just did so outside of the coroutine (and therefore outside the function that may be executed later). Your analysis obviously is correct and it now works (as part of a pointcloud streaming service) like a charm. Interesting though that it worked so reliably different depending on optimization. Many thanks, an upvote and an accepted-answer flag. Best, Richard